# Writing shrugging ASCII emoji ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ in plain text with java

Tags: java, encoding, ascii, emoji, ascii-art

I am developing a java program that writtes output in a text file. When something goes wrong, I must put this ASCII art:

```
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

I did it with this `BufferedOutputStream`:

```
errorOutput.writeln("##################################\n"
                    + "#####       Error Output     ######\n"
                    + "#####       ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯       ######\n"
                    + "##################################\n");
```

The problem is that when I see the txt log writted with java I get this:

```
##################################
#####       Error Output    ######
#####       Â¯\_(ãƒ„)_/Â¯       ######
##################################
```

How can I write the correct ASCII emoji in Java?

Comment: For a start, this is in no way ASCII.

Comment: Oh, and OP: If you haven't read this yet, I would highly recommend it: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html (not trying to be harsh here, but it may clear up a lot of confusion now and into the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with these snippets of code:

```java
@GET
@Path("getStdErr/{idApp}")
@Produces("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
public Response getStdErr(@PathParam("idApp") Integer idApp) {
    return super.getStderr(jobsMap.get(idApp));
}
```

```java
.
.
.
.
return Response.ok(job.getStdErr(), "text/plain; charset=UTF-8").build();
```

Comment: Would `getStdErr()` just return the emoji?

Answer (score 6):

Saving the `.java` file as `UTF-8` this code works for me:

```
String string = "##################################\n"
            + "#####       Error Output     ######\n"
            + "#####       ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯       ######\n"
            + "##################################\n";
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(string);
System.out.println(string);
```

OUTPUT:

```
##################################
#####       Error Output     ######
#####       ¯\_(ツ)_/¯       ######
##################################
```

[DEMO HERE](https://ideone.com/LhyPlH).

Answer (score 2):

The file is in UTF-8, but you are viewing it in a single-byte encoding:

- You are seeing UTF-8 multi-byte sequences for special chars with a char per byte.

Ensure that you read it as UTF-8, because you are indeed using non-ASCII, comma-like, quotes and Japanese. So UTF-8 is fine.

A dirty trick under Windows would be:

```java
String string = "\uFEFF##...
```

This writes a Unicode BOM char, which when being the first char of a file is interpreted as Unicode marker.

Otherwise create an HTML file with charset specified:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>...</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Displaying on the console, System.out, is not possible on a non-UTF-8 system like Windows.

Also for your application to be portable, make sure you specify the encoding for the writing; it often is an optional argument, with an overriden method/constructor.

Comment: i tryed to specify the encoding but did not work: Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(string);
   errorOutput.writeln(string);

Comment: `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8")` is one of many possibilities to have a conversion for text, (`String, Writer`) (which in java always is Unicode) to bytes (`byte[], OutputStream`). But the file already seems okay, as UTF-8. The editor only needs to know it is UTF-8. Use JEdit or Notepad++.

Comment: `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(string); errorOutput.writeln(string);`---this is clearly wrong. You ignore the return value of `encode`, then just send the same string you had before into `errorOutput`. And btw `errorOutput` would have to be an `OutputStream`, not a `Writer`, for that to work.